# TypeError: globalMap.removeLayer is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to remove a layer from a map application; however, I keep getting an error that `removeLayer` is not a function despite it being listed in the [MapboxGL API](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#removelayer).

Supposedly, I am trying to have globalMap extend from map. I was able to add the lines using `globalMap.addSource` and `globalMap.addLayer`, but I get this error when I try to remove them: `TypeError: globalMap.removeLayer is not a function`.

I am importing MapboxGL.

```
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
```

```
const [globalMap, setMap] = useState(Object());
setMap(map);
```

Later in code,

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Good morning line 235!");
    console.log(props);
    console.log("Good morning line 237!");

    if(props.show /* && onlyRunOnce == 0 */) {

      console.log("Good morning line 240!");
      console.log(props);
      var northEast = [131.308594, 46.195042];
      var southEast = [117.597656, 8.233237];
      var southWest = [79.101563, 32.842674];
      var northWest = [86.847656, 44.715514];

      // Add bounding box to the map

      globalMap.addSource('newroute', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'properties': {},
            'geometry': {
                'type': 'LineString',
                'coordinates': [
                    northEast, southEast, southWest, northWest, northEast
                ]
            }
        }
      });

      // Draws bounding box
      globalMap.addLayer({
        'id': 'newroute',
        'type': 'line',
        'source': 'newroute',
        'layout': {
            'line-join': 'round',
            'line-cap': 'round'
        },
        'paint': {
            'line-color': '#ff0000',
            'line-width': 5
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      globalMap.removeLayer('newroute');
      globalMap.removeSource('newroute');
    }
  });
```

Comment: `setMap(map)` <- I dont see you declare `map` in your code.

Comment: @HoangLe sorry I forgot to include it... it is declared earlier in my code

Comment: so I reckon you  re-check it. And fyi, if you want to update `globalMap` with useState(), `globalMap.addSource(...)` is not the way to do it. `setMap({**updates go here**})` should be used. Check this document for more details [React-hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).  If you still stuck, pls provide more details code. Cheers

Comment: Can you add the details about map init?